# Power Automate web, using Compose get URL out of text

Tags: power-automate

I want to extract a URL in an email that has about three and download it.
I have the below flow.

1. When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2)
2. Html to text
3. Compose (but having trouble here)

(When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox (V2))
Added action to
(Html to text) in Content, used Dynamic content outputs.
View the code below.

```
    {
  "type": "OpenApiConnection",
  "inputs": {
    "parameters": {
      "Content": "<p>@{triggerOutputs()}</p>"
    },
    "host": {
      "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_conversionservice",
      "connection": "shared_conversionservice",
      "operationId": "HtmlToText"
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {}
}
```

This produced an output of this.

```
Download Periodic Report
[\"http://email.notifications.xxxxxxxx.xxx/c/nQA1I0dYLR0M88n97jlMuWwxXvZ6k6QuVKj22P42HL9bENp16-_AQAA__-bGnPH\"]
and more URLs in similar formats
```

So, I need to get the URL following the following as my Compose output. It is the link after text Download Periodic Report

```
http://email.notifications.xxxxxxxx.xxx/c/nQA1I0dYLR0M88n97jlMuWwxXvZ6k6QuVKj22P42HL9bENp16-_AQAA__-bGnPH
```

I have tried this expression but have not had any luck.

```
substring(outputs('Html_to_text'), add(indexOf(outputs('Html_to_text'), 'Download Periodic Report ["') + length('Download Periodic Report ["'), 0), sub(indexOf(outputs('Html_to_text'), '"]'), add(indexOf(outputs('Html_to_text'), 'Download Periodic Report ["') + length('Download Periodic Report ["'), 0)))
```

Show raw outputs

```
Download Periodic Report\n[\\\"http://.....bGnPH\\\"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using `split`:

```
split(
  coalesce(
    split(
      string(outputs('Html_to_text')) , 
      'Download Periodic Report\n[\\\"'
    )?[1],
    ''
  ),
  '\\\"]'
)[0]
```

Comment: Hi, Sam, I appreciate the support. it failed, and I got this error. 
InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'split' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Object'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#split for usage details.'.

Comment: Updated above, wrapped it with `string(...) `

Comment: Thanks, Sam. That works, but it has passed a blank output. Would it be possible to share the email or output from the (Html to text) with you so that you can see what I may be missing?

Comment: Update your question above with the output from the flow run for the `Html to text` action. Also share what the input to it is as well.

Comment: Hi, Sam, I appreciate the support. Updated now I hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a line break between `Report` `[`?

Comment: I am not sure how to tell that. I will add and image of what I see in the output.
I just found this. In the raw output section. I will add it above.

Comment: I don't know about the Show Raw Outputs view it shows the blow.
Download Periodic Report\n[\\\"http://

Comment: Yes, there is a line break (see `\n` in the raw output). Updated the answer above to include the line break.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256722/discussion-between-carly-carlyle-adams-cnf-and-sam-nseir).